# how to bring out the similar values in between two csv files and creating a new csv file with desired output in python?

Tags: python, csv

hi I have two csv files which are boom.csv and kaboom.csv which has data like this

boom.csv

```
id;rollnumber;total;subjects;obtained;rank;standing
260406;260737;137;10;127;10;111
552592;260806;134;10;124;10;108
402788;260837;134;10;124;10;108
262744;260851;131;10;121;10;105
502870;260874;131;10;121;10;105
342541;260879;131;10;121;10;105
502806;260902;135;10;125;10;109
261664;261182;217;21;196;15;161
```

and kaboom.csv consists of data like this 
kaboom.csv

```
    id
342541
552592
402788
502806
502870
```

here im trying to compare these both files and trying to bring out the data which is common in between them and storing them into a new csv file.. 
to be more exact.. im considering the "id" values in  kaboom.csv and comparing it with the id values of boom.csv and trying to create a new csv file which consists of only identical ids with its entire row of values associated with it which are rollnumber, total   subjects, obtained, rank, standing

desired output:-
bigbang.csv

```
     id          rollnumber   total   subjects   obtained   rank   standing

     402788      260837        134     10        124        10      108
     552592      260806        134     10        124        10      108
     502870      260874        131     10        121        10      105
     342541      260879        131     10        121        10      105
     502806      260902        135     10        125        10      109
```

can anyone help with this? how to do it python?

Comment: hi, the code is running but the output in the excel is like this
id,rollnumber,total,subjects,obtained,rank,standing
no values in it..
im really sorry i forgot to mention how my data looks.. its all scrambled tbh..maybe that´s the reason it didnt give me a proper output when executed..
i´ll update it in my question.. my sincere apologies for this.

Comment: sure, im updating my question @DeveshKumarSingh...

Comment: hi @DeveshKumarSingh i have edited my question and im really sorry. it all happened because of my ignorance.

Comment: So the code is working, just that the data is not in the format you want? @gendry?

Comment: ýes, exactly...

Comment: Okay I updated my answer, I just added a tab delimiter to the csv writer, try again @gendry!

Comment: and im not able to ask another question due to 90mins waiting time..
unlucky me :/

Comment: No issues, Just check the last part of the code, should work as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas, you can easily load CSV files as dataframes and merge them by column:

```
import pandas as pd

boom = pd.read_csv('boom.csv',sep = ';')
kaboom = pd.read_csv('kaboom.csv',header=0,names=['id'])
bigbang = pd.merge(boom, kaboom, on="id")

print(bigbang)
```

Output:

```
       id  rollnumber  total  subjects  obtained  rank  standing
0  552592      261347    243        16       227    19       174
1  402788      261381    231        16       215    19       164
2  502870      262871    248        22       226    21       151
3  342541      267359    117         8       108     8       106
4  502806      261664    235        14       221    15       173
```

You can then easily write the resulting dataframe to a CSV file with:

```
bigbang.to_csv('bigbang.csv',sep = ' ',index = False)
```

Comment: If you CSV files are comma-separated not space-separated, try replacing `sep = '\s+'` and `sep = ' '` with `sep = ','`

Comment: hi! i have modified my csv file and made it into a proper format which is.. 9 rows x 7 columns.. still the same error pops up.. any suggestions?

Comment: Include the actual CSV file (not copy pasted from Excel, copy it from Notepad for example) in your post and I'll adjust my code accordingly.

Comment: sure.. give me a moment

Comment: hi i have updated boom.csv and kaboom.csv as you told me.. copied it from notepad

Answer (score 0):

We start by getting all items from `boom.csv` and `kaboom.csv` by reading the csv file via the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

```
boom_items = []

#Iterate over csv and read all rows
with open('boom.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ',  skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)
    boom_items = [row for row in reader]

kaboom_items = []

#Iterate over csv and read all rows
with open('kaboom.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ',  skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)
    kaboom_items = [row for row in reader]
```

Then we iterate over both loops, and find common id's

```
bigbang_items = [ item_2 for item_1 in kaboom_items for item_2 in boom_items if item_1[0] == item_2[0]]
```

Then we save this list to `bigbang.csv`

```
headers =  ['id','rollnumber','total','subjects','obtained','rank','standing']
with open('bigbang.csv','w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(bigbang_items)
```

Hence the `bigbang.csv` would look like

```
id  rollnumber  total   subjects    obtained    rank    standing
342541  267359  117 8   108 8   106
552592  261347  243 16  227 19  174
402788  261381  231 16  215 19  164
502806  261664  235 14  221 15  173
502870  262871  248 22  226 21  151
```

Comment: Hi @gentry , are you getting empty output in csv, can you check how `bigbang_items` looks like, I took the data from the question itself

Comment: Check answer again @gendry!

Comment: its the same.. .:/
the csv file looks like this
id,rollnumber,total,subjects,obtained,rank,standing
everything in one row and one column

Comment: Did you use the `writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')` line? It should cause the commas to go away @gendry

Comment: yes! i did.. 
the data i have right now in my csv file is 9rows x 1column..
maybe that is what´s messing up? i guess?

Comment: I think it has something to do with delimiters, I am assuming my csv is spaced by multiple whitespaces, is that the same thing you see? Also what does `print(bigbang.csv)` give you? Does it give you a list of lists @gendry?

Comment: You mean the output csv, or the input csv has 9 rows x 1 column?                         
If it is output csv,  I think it has something to do with delimiters, I am assuming my csv is spaced by multiple whitespaces, is that the same thing you see? Also what does print(bigbang.csv) give you? Does it give you a list of lists @gendry?

Comment: no no. i have fixed my csv according to the format i needed.. 9rows and 7 columns..

Comment: Then what’s the issue, i am not able to understand, just check the values for boom_items kaboom_items and bigbang_items when you run my code, it should help you resolve the issue . I used the data you gave me and it works perfectly @gendry :) Also if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: i typed the data manually,, maybe that´s causing an issue.. ill update the data for one last time and im really sorry for bothering you..

Comment: Yes as I said, debug my code line by line, use print statements on variables, it should tell you what’s going on and no worries We want to solve the issue @gentry

Comment: thank you so much.. i have updated my boom.csv and kaboom.csv accordingly..now maybe we could take a look it..and ill do as you told me..

Comment: it worked...the issue is resolved..thank you so much for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrames are loaded as `df_initial` and `df_compare` (more readable than boom and kaboom), a simple merge would suffice:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df_init,df_compare, on = 'id', how='left')
```

To expand, this command will search through both df's and return rows with matching id's. Additional data from the *left* df will be included.

> I've included a longer version of this solution on [this collab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ybressler/2f0f690657aaa28728641438b02bd0bf/merging-dfs-help.ipynb).